# CSS not working with API Iframe

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a social login plugin to connect with my site. It works fine, but I want to remove its mark, like **Powered By AJAY**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".ajay iframe").contents().find("#branding").attr("style","display:none");
    });
</script>
```

I try to display none with its class and id but it does not work because all part come with frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delay jquery css override with 2s delay, to see if this applies the modifications well or not. To change delay time, modify 2000 (2s) to whatever you want (1000 = 1second, 9000 = 9s, etc.)
You want to wait since when the page has finished loading, so put that code inside your $(document).ready(...); script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){   
        jQuery(".ajay iframe").contents().find("#branding").attr("style","display:none"); 
     ;}, 2000);
})
```

UPDATE: jquery 1.4.0 introduced the .delay method. [Check it out.](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

I dont know if you want it to modify a wordpress or a handmade webpage, anyway i did it some times using CSS, let me search for the classes i applied and i'll edit the answer. I need to know which social iframe are you loading.. facebook maybe? twitter? the solution is not the same sometimes due to the code charged by the iframe.

i let here an example and a code snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(document.body).append("it's gonna be legen-... wait for it");
         setTimeout(function(){
            alert("-dary!!")
         ;}, 4000);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Oh and... if you could update the question with the code you want to modify after loading will be fine to build a proper css

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until iframe is loaded, also iframe need to be in the same domain as your page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".ajay iframe").load(function() {  
        jQuery(this).contents().find("#branding").
            attr("style","display:none");
    });
});
```